# Pick a Topic Model

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am new to topic modeling and kind of confused. I have run MALLET various times with different values for the number of topics. So how do I know which one to choose for further analysis? I know that there are papers out there dealing with evaluation of topic models, but I can't code something like this.

Comment: If you can't code something like this and you are asking this question on SO, a coding question and answer platform, I'm confused what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of the number of topics as a natural characteristic of your documents. They aren't really combinations of multinomial distributions, so there is no "right" answer. There is a wide range of good values.

You should think of the number of topics as the scale of a map of your collection. If you want a broad overview, use fewer topics. If you want more detail, use more. The right number is the value that produces meaningful results that allow you to accomplish your goal.